# Loading JavaScript in Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I'm trying to initiate a JS file when clicking on a link "link_to" in my rails app.

I ensured the the  asset pipeline is working correctly by testing with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

and the alert popups without a problem.

However, the script only loads when I refresh after the page is loaded. I've tried the code below without any luck but as I said, it works once the page is reload.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  //My JS Code

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I have the Turbolinks gem file complied Gem file below

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.slimscroll
//= require app
//= require zopim
//= require turbolinks
```

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing. I've seen examples using coffee script but I don't know enough about it to use it at this time.

**Edit:**

While monitoring Network under Chrome Dev tools, I noticed  that none of the JS load until I hit F5 to reload the page but I don't seem to have problems with the other scripts. This might be a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this ?

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this worked for me. `var ready;
ready = function() {
// My JS code
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('turbolinks:reload', ready);`

Comment: You have `reload` instead of `load`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  //My JS Code
})
```

This should work for you.